# android workmanager is not working when app suspends need suggestion

Tags: android

`WorkManager` set with periodically but when app get killed the scheduler not work.

I need run form api version 23 to 29

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest refreshCpnWork =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(RefreshLatestCouponWorker.class, 15*60*1000L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setConstraints(myConstraints)
                        .setInputData(source)
                        .build();
```

Comment: Is it being killed on emulator or on a real device?

Comment: i have test on real device and android nougat version 7.0-

Comment: how can i get solution , I have not found  any solution till now. When app suspended background sync data to serever

Comment: Show us your worker. What kind of background job does it do?

Comment: var periodicWorkRequest: PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<TestWorker>(16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setInputData(data)
            .setConstraints(constraint).build() WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("periodic_work_request", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWorkRequest) def work_version = '2.0.1'
    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

Comment: i am using above code

Comment: I meant the RefreshLatestCouponWorker class... And put it please inside your question.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you  about RefreshLatestCouponWorker class but i am running very simple codeclass TestWorker(context: Context, parameter: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, parameter) {


    override fun doWork(): Result {
        var dataString = inputData.getString("data_to_send")
        Log.v("Test Worker :", "Worker executed with data :" + dataString)


        return Result.success()
    }
}

Comment: requirement we have that we need to send data to server very 2 hours condition even when  app is suspended  data should be send background , i have used alarm manager and services due to android restriction we cant use it.

Comment: hi  mark i have send you code details

Comment: Hi, it turns out I use this dependency: "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02" in my application. I've pushed a small app to github: https://github.com/markowerzeczy/myWorker . It is sending a notification every 15 minutes. It's working fine even after force stop. I tested it on HUAWEI Android 8.1.0. Go ahead and try this one out.

Comment: Did you manage to pull and try out my app?

Comment: you sent code is working for most of the device except mi devices. please let me know if you any solution for mi, vivo

Comment: What is your device exactly? The name, model and Android version?

Comment: device name redmi, model note 6 pro, android version8.1,0, miui version 10.2.2.0

Comment: Have you read this: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi ?

Comment: thanks you markwalczak.  but today i have tested on one plus device, work manager stopped working conditionally when user select option on battery optimization

Comment: Are you sure the worker stopped? Or mabe it was just delayed? Workers are not as accurate as AlarmManager. It is supposed to wait until the device is in best state to perform action. Sometimes it takes 10 or 20 minutes. So maybe your worker would start again after a longer while...

Answer (score 0):

I've found  that some devices like HUAWEI has a feature called “power-intensive app monitor“.

It kills every app that runs in the background for a long time unless user gives special permissions to it.

The path to do this: Settings -> Security & privacy -> Location services -> recent location requests: YOUR APP NAME -> Battery -> uncheck Power-intensive prompt, App launch: Manage manually: check all three positions: Auto-launch, Secondary launch, Run in background.

I don’t know if there's a way to do this programmatically. I think the best way is to create a sort of help activity and explain the user what to do if application won’t work.